# Python: How to take tar using tarfile module by excluding the 3rd directory

Tags: python, linux, shell, tarfile

I have the directory structure like this

```
-- jenkins
|-- jobs
|   |-- dir1
|   |   |-- build_dir--
|   |   `-- Autoyes
|   |-- dir2
|   |   |-- build_dir--
|   |   `-- Manyes
|   |-- dir3
|   |   |-- ArtFict
|   |   `-- build_dir--
|   `-- hi
|-- tesst
`-- tets
```

I need to take a tar using tarfile module by excluding the  **"build_dir"** under all **dir1,dir2,dir3** and more directories.
I can use a very simple tar statement into subprocess to achieve this

```
tar --exclude="*/*/buid_dir" -czvf test.tgz jenkins
```

But I'm looking for a pythonic way to achieve this, so far what I have done is not excluding the "build_dir" directory.

```
import tarfile
import os,sys
import subprocess

def ProcesS (input):
    Asub = subprocess.Popen (input,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output,error = Asub.communicate()
    return output,error

A = ['jenkins', 'jenkins/jobs', 'jenkins/jobs/dir1', 'jenkins/jobs/dir1/build_dir', 'jenkins/jobs/dir2', 'jenkins/jobs/dir2/build_dir', 'jenkins/jobs/dir3', 'jenkins/jobs/dir3/build_dir']

Tar = tarfile.open('Backme.tgz','w:gz')

#Tar.add(A,exclude='*/*/build_dir')   #This throws the error

Tar.add(A)     # creates a tar file without excluding the build_dir 
Tar.close()
```

It would be much helpful if someone finds the answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation

```
TarFile.add(name, arcname=None, recursive=True, exclude=None, filter=None)
```

it looks like you would just add it to excludes (you may have to put the full path ...)

it looks like you do

```
tf = tarfile.open("sometar.tar","w")
def excludes_fn(name):
    return "build" in name
tf.add("/base/folder",exclude=excludes_fn)
```

Comment: I tried the way you have mentioned. The build directory is excluding completely even it in jenkins/build.

Comment: yeah you may need to define the function to exclude based on other conditions then my example ...